# How to avoid OS X downloading things while using tethering

Tags: wifi, firewall, tethering, internet-sharing

When on the road, I would like to use my phone's LTE connection and tether it to my macbook.

However, I do not have an unlimited data plan, so I don't want the mac to download a bunch of stuff (OS X updates, Chrome updates, and so forth) and kill my monthly allowance.

As far as I know, when tethering from the mac side it looks like a regular wlan connection, so I am not sure if there is an easy way to do this. I use Little Snitch, so I was considering creating a restrictive profile there to block connections when in this mode. Is there an obvious way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: MacOS Ventura 13 which launched on October 24, 2022,  [includes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449668/what-is-low-data-mode-on-macos-ventura-wlan-exactly/460953#460953) "Low Data Mode" which you can set on all Wi-Fi connections, including tethered ones. It is under *Apple menu > System Settings > Wi-Fi* in the sidebar or *Menu Bar \> Wi-Fi status icon > Wi-Fi Settings... .* Then for the active connection at the top *Details... > Low data mode*