# What is "Low Data Mode" on macOS Ventura WLAN exactly?

Tags: network, wifi, ventura

What is "Low Data Mode" on macOS Ventura WLAN exactly? I found only a description for the [feature in iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210596).

Does it only limit traffic for Apple Apps? Or also 3rd party Open Source Apps?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature is available to all developers - also third party developers and developers of Open Source apps.

When the developer makes a program on macOS, and ask the operating system to create a network connection, they can specify whether or not that connection should be made when Low Data Mode is enabled.

However, Low Data Mode is a new feature in macOS Ventura, so the number of third party programs that support this feature right now is quite low. In time that will probably change.

Answer (score 4):

Full description for iPhone and iPad [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210596)

Retrieved 2023-01-18

> ## Use Low Data Mode on your iPhone and iPad
>
> ### What to expect in Low Data Mode
>
> Different apps use different ways of reducing data usage in Low Data
> Mode. In general, here's what you can expect:
>
> - Apps might stop using network data when you're not actively using them.
> - Background App Refresh is turned off.
> - The quality of streaming content might be reduced.
> - Automatic downloads and backups are turned off.
> - Services such as iCloud Photos pause updates.
>
> Built-in iOS apps and services adapt to Low Data Mode in the following
> ways:
>
> - App Store: Video autoplay, automatic updates, and automatic downloads are turned off.
> - Music: Automatic downloads and high quality streaming are turned off.
> - Podcasts: The frequency of feed updates is limited, and episodes are downloaded only on Wi-Fi.
> - News: Article prefetching is turned off.
> - iCloud: Updates are paused, and automatic backups and iCloud Photos updates are turned off.
> - FaceTime: Video bitrate is optimized for lower bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

It has been [documented](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-wi-fi-settings-on-mac-mh11935/13.0/mac/13.0#mchldb2b7302) for macOS Ventura 13:

> ### Change Wi-Fi settings on Mac
>
> #### Details button settings
>
> | Option | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | Low data mode | Turn on low data mode to help reduce your data usage over the Wi-Fi network. |

([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230117064027/https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-wi-fi-settings-on-mac-mh11935/13.0/mac/13.0))

### How to get to the setting

Since macOS Ventura 13 [launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MacOS_Ventura&oldid=1159506143#:%7E:text=launched%20on%20October%2024%2C%202022) in October 24, 2022 it is available under

- *Apple menu [image] > System Settings > Wi-Fi [image]*  in the sidebar, or
- *Menu Bar >  Wi-Fi status icon  [image] / [image] / [image] > Wi-Fi Settings...*

Then for the active connection at the top

- *Details... > Low data mode*

Comment: What do you need an archive for? The Apple article provides different versions of the article from High Sierra to Ventura.

Comment: For the future.

Comment: Very mysterious here. What do you mean?

Comment: Apple is [neither](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21376744) [good](https://v4.chriskrycho.com/2019/apple-your-developer-documentation-is-garbage.html) at providing extensive documentation  [nor preserving it long time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239484/does-apple-provide-a-web-site-with-content-of-man-pages-for-the-command-line-c/239485#239485).